# Fetch data with one row and one column from table using Perl DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

I am trying to fetch data like (`Select 1 from table`) which returns data with one row and one column.

I dont want to use `$sth->fetchrow_array` method to retreive the data in to array. Is there any way to collect the data into scalar variable direclty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fetchrow_array` returns a list —it's impossible to return an array— and you can assign that to anything [list-like](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) such as a `my()`.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute();
my ($var) = $sth->fetchrow_array()
   and $sth->finish();
```

Or you could simply use

```
my ($var) = $dbh->selectrow_array($stmt);
```

Comment: The documentation for `fetchrow_array`  and `selectrow_array` imply they'll return either the first or last column when called in scalar context, so while the parens in `my ($var) = ...` are normally significant, it should be possible to omit them here.

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($value) = @{$dbh−>selectcol_arrayref("select 1 from table")}
```

or better

```
my ($value) = $dbh−>selectrow_array($statement);
```